# What is a check matrix for the linear code $\{0,1\}$?

Tags: coding-theory

If a binary linear code $C = \{0,1\}$, then it is $1$-dimensional and its generator matrix $G$ is $[1]$.

It's dual code will be $\{0\}$ and $0$-dimensional and has basis $\{\}$.

**Then what is a check matrix $H$ for $C$??**

As $H$ is defined to be a matrix whose rows form a basis for $C$'s dual, I gather from the above that H does not exist.

But we know that $HG^T=0$, which means that $H=[0]$.

We also know that if $G=[I|A]$, then $H=[-A^T|I]$, which means that $H=[1]$.

I'm contradicting myself all over; please help me sort this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't come up much in elementary linear algebra classes, but a matrix can have dimension $0 \times n$, $n \times 0$, or even $0 \times 0$ (where $n$ is a positive integer).

It can be a little tricky to deal with if it's your first time dealing with vacuous things.

So by the definition you gave, $H$ has to be a $0 \times 1$ matrix.

The product $HG^T$ is the product of a $0 \times 1$ matrix with a $1 \times 1$ matrix, and thus has dimension $0 \times 1$. There is only one $0 \times 1$ matrix, so $HG^T$ is automatically the zero matrix of that dimension.

Some other things to note: if $A$ is defined by that matrix equation with $G$, then that means $A$ is a $1 \times 0$ matrix. This is consistent with the formula for $H$ which adjoins $-A^T$ -- a $0 \times 1$ matrix -- with the $0 \times 0$ identity matrix.

(note that the $0\times 0$ identity matrix is the same as the $0 \times 0$ zero matrix)

Since there is only one $0 \times 1$ matrix, it does indeed give the correct formula for $H$.

Comment: Fascinating!! Just one question: In the formula $HG^T=0$, the LHS is the $0$x$1$ zero matrix, but isn't the RHS the $1$x$1$ zero matrix? Or is it that when we admit these werid-sized matrices, the number zero ought to be generalised too to be understand as the zero matrix of any dimension?

Comment: The latter; in matrix algebra, $0$ is often used as shorthand for the zero matrix of whatever dimension makes sense. So, in this case, it stands for the $0 \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: I am so glad I decided to ask this on stackexchange instead of waving it aside. THANK YOU for such a wonderfully enligtening answer! I wish I could upvote this answer 5 times!

Comment: Hey Hurkyl, if time permits, do you mind to take a look at my follow-up question? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/378053/21813  Thanks.