# Minimum distance of the linear code $\{0,1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

> Let $H$ be a check matrix for a linear code $C$. Then the minimum distance
>   of $C$ is $d \in \mathbb N$ such that there exists a set of $d$, but no set of $d-1$, linearly dependent columns in $H$.

1) Am I right to surmise from the above thorem that $C$ has minimum distance $1$ iff. $H$ contains a column of zeros?

2) Consider the linear code $\{0,1\}$ whose minimum distance is clearly $1$. Its check matrix $H$ is the $0$x$1$ zero matrix, so $H$ has $0$ linearly dependent columns. This contradicts the above theorem, doesn't it?

Comment: I recommed rephrasing your point 1) to read "$C$ has minimum distance $1$ iff $H$ contains a column of weight zero." This will cure problem in 2) in the sense that an empty column can be meaningfully defined to have weight zero :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation in (1) looks correct. The empty set is never linearly dependent, and a set with one vector can only be linearly dependent if that vector is zero.

For (2), while a $0 \times 1$ matrix has zero rows, it does have one column. In this case, the one column is the zero vector (of the zero-dimensional vector space), and so your $H$ does have a zero column.

Comment: THANKS again. You were damn right (and prophetic) when you earlier said, "[0×1 matrices] can be a little tricky to deal with if it's your first time dealing with vacuous things."

Comment: Yep. While I think it's valuable to learn how to deal with them, I can definitely understand why some people prefer to exclude degenerate cases and treat problems where they would arise in an ad-hoc manner.

Answer (score 1):

1) is right, and here is the way to think about it. Suppose you have two codewords that are exactly the minimum distance apart, say $x$ and $y$. This means that there is a vector $e$ such that $x+e=y$ and $e$ has weight $d$.

Since $e=y-x$, $e$ is in the code, and so multiplying it with the parity check results in the zero matrix. The $d$ entries witness that the corresponding $d$ columns are linearly dependent. The existence of a smaller nonzero weight codeword would contradict the definition of $d$ as the mininum distance, so every set of $d-1$ columns must be linearly independent.

If the code has distance 1, it contains a codeword of weight 1. Of course, for this to have zero product with the parity check matrix, the corresponding column must be zero.

2) As you've found out already, there is no contradiction with 1), it's just that the $d-1$ statement breaks down since you can't talk about "a set of $-1$ LI vectors", and there is this 0 dimension degeneracy.

At any rate, this concern is just academic since the usefulness of the generator matrix and parity check matrix disappear for linear codes $d=1$. For such a code you can instantly identify all codewords and dual codewords, and the code neither detects nor corrects errors.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Coding theory has to be in the top 5 topics of mathematics that are the most fun to learn and teach :)

Comment: Oh I agree. I began in 1968 and it has not grown stale on me as yet!